# The NBA's New Flopping Rule -- Any Official Records?

Tags: rules, nba

Most NBA fans are aware of the new flopping rule that was imposed this season. You can find details about it [here](http://www.nba.com/2012/news/10/29/nba-flopping-rules.ap/index.html). The basic idea is that whenever the NBA determines that a player has flopped, he gets a warning for the first offense and a fine for the rest.

Most of the time, I get news about flopping via articles on the web (e.g. [here](http://www.nba.com/search/?text=flop) and [here](http://www.star-telegram.com/2012/12/19/4497742/fall-guys-nbas-no-flopping-rule.html)), but is there an official web page that contains data about the full list of those who have been warned or fined? I couldn't find one by doing a brief search on ESPN or NBA.com.

Comment: As of 19 December 2012, there were [nine violators](http://www.star-telegram.com/2012/12/19/4497742/fall-guys-nbas-no-flopping-rule.html) based on the new flopping rule.

Comment: And this is merely a [source request](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/218/527)...which isn't constructive on Sports SE.

Comment: Note: I posted the same link in my "question."